# Convert object to int (Pandas Dataframe)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have seen this question asked several times, but I haven't found an answer that solves my problem yet.  I have a CSV file that reads in the values as objects and I haven't found a way to convert a column to an int (column may contain None values).  This is what I have tried:

```
df = pd.read_csv("workouts.csv",
                 converters={'Length (minutes)': lambda x: pd.to_numeric(
                     x, errors='ignore')}
```

```
df['Length (minutes)'] = df['Length (minutes)'].astype('int', errors='ignore')
```

```
df['Length (minutes)'] = df['Length (minutes)'].astype('str').astype('int', errors='ignore')
```

After all of the above, I get:

```
>>> df.dtypes
Workout Timestamp      object
Live/On-Demand         object
Instructor Name        object
Length (minutes)       object
```

What is the trick do convert this to an int?

Comment: Show us your CSV file.

Comment: `int` is a basic processor level type and they don't have a "none" value. You need to convert that "none" to some integer value first. Is there some rational integer value to use instead? Alternately, you could use `float` which has a NaN value.

Comment: @tdelaney I thought errors=ignore would take care of this.  I will give it a try.

Comment: @cicit - The help says you have two choices when a value won't convert: Raise an error or keep the original object. A column can only have a single data type, so when something fails to convert, that column has to be `object` again. The help isn't 100% correct. If you had a mix of `int` and `None` for instance, you'd end up with a `float`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Tdelaney solved this for me.  I used:

```
df['Length (minutes)'] = pd.to_numeric(df['Length (minutes)'], errors='coerce')
```

This converted the entire column to a float64 and now I can math on it! :-)